# Parallel execution in Python (process rabbitmq's messages in parallel)

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, rabbitmq

I have a heavy function. Execution this func takes up a lot of computing resources (it's StableDiffusion model from keras framework, but i don't think it matters much). Also, I have message broker sending data for this function. I want to execute function with every message from broker in a separate process.

Multithreading and asyncio can't provide real parallelism in python. I tried multiprocessing, but programm still works sequentially.

Here is example using multiprocessing:

*That heavy function:*

```
def generate_image(message, id):
    model = StableDiffusion(img_height=512, img_width=512, jit_compile=True)
    img = model.text_to_image(
        prompt=message,
        batch_size=1,  # How many images to generate at once
        num_steps=10,  # Number of iterations (controls image quality)
        seed=1539,  # Set this to always get the same image from the same prompt
    )
    image_name = 'images/' + id + '.png'
    Image.fromarray(img[0]).save(image_name)
```

Function to read RabbitMQ (take it from aio_pika doc: https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html#simple-consumer)

```
async def main() -> None:
    connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust("amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/",)
    queue_name = "requestQueue"

    async with connection:
        # Creating channel
        channel = await connection.channel()
        # Will take no more than 10 messages in advance
        await channel.set_qos(prefetch_count=10)
        # Declaring queue
        queue = await channel.declare_queue(queue_name, auto_delete=False, durable=True)
        async with queue.iterator() as queue_iter:
            async for message in queue_iter:
                async with message.process():
                    json_str = json.loads(message.body)
                    generate_image(json_str.get('message'), json_str.get('id'))
```

And my attempt to run the processing process in parallel:

```
def between_func():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Process(target=between_func())
    t2 = Process(target=between_func())
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

How to execute these functions in parallel using multithreading? Or maybe using another instruments?

Comment: If you'd like people to assist, it's best to provide a _complete_ set of code that can be run, preferably via a code hosting service (like GitHub or GitLab). Right now you're asking people to guess at what you're trying to accomplish. For instance, there is no relation between your "attempt to run in parallel" code and the rest of what you have provided. If you can't provide a complete sample, provide something that mimics what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that is works for me. I achieved truly parallel execution (every execution of function worked two times slower, but at the same time).

```
import pika
import multiprocessing

# Function for processing messages from the queue
def process_message(channel, method, properties, body):
    print("Received message:", body)

# Function to create a process that will listen to the queue
def listen_to_queue():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='my_queue')
    channel.basic_consume(queue='my_queue', on_message_callback=process_message, auto_ack=True)
    channel.start_consuming()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create multiple processes to process messages from a queue
    processes = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=listen_to_queue)
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    # Waiting for all processes to end
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```